# changing shape size on a canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am a complete beginner to Android development. I am currently trying to implement a pulsing circle  (so it increases in size and then decreases back to nothing and does this till I want it to stop). I am using a canvas to draw the circle and was wondering how would I change the radius in a steady way and render that?

Currently I am thinking of using a for loop to increase the size of the radius of the circle:

```
for (int i=0; i < 400; i++ ) {
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, i , mPaint)
}
```

but that obviously wouldn't work as it would increase to radius 400 and then stop. Could someone help me with the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom XML theme for the shape you want to use, and from there you can look up the XML design interface from the documentation, it will give you a lot of freedom.